# Apply CSS if text exceeds a certain length

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Is there a way to apply a CSS to an element if the text within the element exceeds a certain length. For instance `<p class="foo">123456789</p>`.

Then, when the text within the element exceeds x characters a new class is applied

```
<p class="foo text-exceeds-X-chars">12345678910101010101</p>
```

Comment: What is your expected behaviour by adding class `text-exceeds-X-chars`?

Comment: If none of the answers work or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `addClass` callback function:

```
$('p.foo').addClass(function() {
    return $.trim(this.textContent).length > 10
           ? 'text-exceeds-X-chars'
           : null;
});
```

Comment: I like your callback approach :)

Comment: Aren't you going to call addClass(null) which would run addClass and be less efficient, rather than checking the text.length and then calling addClass?

Comment: @AaronHarding I didn't race the snippets for checking the performance, but I'm sure that it's much more efficient than explicit `each`  call. jQuery just ignores the `null` value. Plus the above code iterates once, `$().text` method itself implicitly iterates through the collection.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/), then, use `length`. If the condition is fulfilled, use [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to apply the class

```
if($('p.foo').text().length > 20){
    $('p.foo').addClass('my-class');
}
```

If you have multiple `p.foo` elements, do

```
$('p.foo').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().length > 20){
        $(this).addClass('my-class');
    }
});
```

Comment: This will simply fail if there are more than 1 `p.foo` element.

Comment: @Vohuman, you are right. Thanks for the tip. :) Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is not built-in filter or selector for this, so you will have to do it manually. The idea is to select all elements in question and test the length of each of them in loop:

```
$('.foo').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().length > x) {
        $(this).addClass('text-exceeds-X-chars');
    }
});
```

Comment: I Implemented this here http://clients.rocoru.com/speakingfluently.com/index.html, but it doesn't seem to work

The target tag is the <h3 class="title"> underneath the "More from the blog" text